# Website crashing when too many requests happen at once

Tags: apache, queue, silverstripe

We have a website which advertises a competition on TV each month. When the advert runs the website gets around 4000 submissions and this causes it to crash

The website runs off Silverstripe and is hosted on Apache.

I have read about queuing, and this sounds like the solution but I have spoken to the Silverstripe dev and the Server admin and both say that the other needs to make this happen.

My question is should the queuing be done on the website or the server?

Comment: Thanks guys both answers are helpful. I'll have to do a bit more digging until I can accept. Cheers

Comment: Yeah best to dig around to find the best solution for your needs. Sounds like maybe a better server that can handle high loads might be better (maybe more expensive though...). Good luck!

Comment: Job Queues are useful if you have to do heavy work and want to distribute that work or save it for later. But if your problem is actually that the high number of requests overloads your server, then I am not sure a queue will help you there.

Comment: the static publisher module can be useful to speed up your website and reduce load by saving your pages as html files. however, this way you will loose the ability to have dynamic content. alternatively you can use caching services like cloudflare which do roughly the same thing.

Comment: but just blindly optimizing might not get you very far. the first thing you should do is investigate further and find out what your bottle neck really is, and then fix exactly that bottle neck. just randomly changing parts and hoping it gets better might not server you that well.

Comment: Look what just got posted on the official Silverstripe blog: http://www.silverstripe.org/improving-silverstripe-performance/

Answer (score 1):

To help Silverstripe handle lots of requests you can install the Static Publishing module:

http://www.silverstripe.org/introducing-the-static-publish-queue-module/

Your developer would implement that on the website.

This will create a flat version of your website that is served to users. This greatly reduces server load.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of server are you running? You can get many different types these days... for example some do load balancing etc which might help prevent the crashing.

Also there are plenty of third party applications that you could integrate with to help you with job queuing like http://www.iron.io/ or http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/.

Another option is to find a module for silverstripe that already exists... I had a really quick look on github and found a one that *might* do the job you require -
https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-queuedjobs

Let me know how you get on :)

Answer (score 0):

Good overview of all the areas to look at for SilverStripe on http://www.silverstripe.org/improving-silverstripe-performance/.